# Compiler- DFA (a+b)* vs (a|b)* any difference between both?

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, dfa

do (a+b)* and (a|B)* produce the same DFA and same output?
In mathematics, wherever the word 'or' is involved, we use addition operator.
So does that mean that both expressions are equivalent?

Comment: Well, if you say that the first is mathematic notation and the second is regex notation, so that `+` in the first means the same as `|` does in the latter, then yes they are equivalent.

Comment: I am talking in terms of regex notation. 
Please help me out with cfg as well
CFG for (a+b)* will be s->aSbS|^ CFG for (a|b)* will be s-> aS|bS|^ am I working in the right direction?

Comment: No, `(a+b)*` is `Repeat(Concat(Repeat("a", >=1), "b")), >=0)`

Comment: @user3001571 There is more than one regex notation. Different engines and different textbooks use different notations. In most real-life regex engines `+` means "one or more". In some text books (and perhaps some lesser used regex engines), `+` means "or".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context where you get the 2 regular expressions from.

If you interpret both regex in the syntax of real life regex engines, they have different meanings, as [Ed Cottrell explained in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33635262/1400768). `+` means repeating once or more. `|` means alternation.

However, they can mean the exact same thing, if you interpret `+` in `(a+b)*` as *alternation*, following the notation in most books on automata theory, and `|` in `(a|b)*` as *alternation*, following the notation in most real life regex engines.

Answer (score 1):

No.

`(a+b)*` matches at least one `a` followed by a `b`, zero or more times. So, for it to match a non-empty string, the string must, at some point, contain `ab`.

`(a|B)*` requires `a` or `b`, zero or more times. It can match the empty string, a string of all `a`s, a string of all `b`s, etc.

The second expression matches the entire string in the following examples: `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, `b`, `bb`, `bbb`, etc. The first expression technically matches (because a zero-length string would match), but doesn't match the entire string. The captured groups are different.

So, no, they are not equivalent.

Comment: CFG for (a+b)* will be s->aSbS|^
CFG for (a|b)* will be s-> aS|bS|^
am I working in the right direction?

Comment: @user3001571: No, in regex notation the `+` means "one or more", so `a+` = `aa*`

Comment: @user3001571 What Bergi just said.

Answer (score 0):

`(a|b)*` denotes {ε, "a", "b", "aa", "**ab**", "ba", "bb", "aaa", **aab**, abb, aba, baa ...}

`(a+b)*` denotes {ε, ab, aab, aaab, abab, aabab,...}

`ε` denote empty